# Which http testing tool to use for Load-Balancing?

Tags: linux, load-balancing

I am working on some modifications on the Linux Virtual Server. 
I have a small cluster of 3 servers and one director.
I am using Apache as web server, and I would like to make some performance tests, varying some parameters. The information I need is basic: response rate, response time, etc

Some people recommended me httperf and autobenchmark. Which of those (or any other) would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Apache jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)